# Activity closed before server response received

Tags: android, callback

My problem is more an information than a real issue.

Let's say I have an activity A which send a request to a server during onCreate. The activity itself implements the callback for when the response is received. So the procedure is asynchronous.

Now, let's suppose the user starts this activity but before the response is received, the user closes the activity.

So, when the app receives the response... What happen?
Does the app still work? Or will it throw a null pointer exception because the activity (and therefore the callback) does not exist anymore?

For the last case, which may be a good solution? Start a service for the request? Or something else?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code where you do your async process.

Comment: Nothing will happen.  Since the callback no longer exists, the response will simply be ignored.  If this is not what you want, then a service is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your doing very wrong. Never use activities on create method for any network calls. onCreate method is meant for setting up ui element for user interface, all the network call should happen in on resume.

if you start network call in onresume and user didnt wait for its result and quits the activity, nothing will happen since u called in onResume.You should have handle that task by cancelling that task.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an AsyncTask,  there is a `cancel()` method available to you.  Using the DownloadFilesTask example on this page:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

In your activity, add a field called myTask as an instance of DownloadFilesTask and set it on your onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.myTask = new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
}
```

Then in onPause you [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) it:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (this.myTask != null){
        this.myTask.cancel(true);
        this.myTask = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

If you aren't using an AsyncTask,  my apologies it wasnt known at the time of writing this,   consider using it.